# Sections of a sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, differential-topology

In algebraic geometry, specifically Hartshorne, for a given sheaf $\mathscr{F}$, we say that the sections of the sheaf over some open set $U$ are merely elements $s \in \mathscr{F} (U)$.

However, I believe sections is also used in other mathematical fields such as differential topology. In particular, I recently saw in Liu's book where he has the following definition:

> Let $\pi: X \to S$ be an $S$-scheme. A section of $X$ is a morphism $\sigma : S \to X$.

What is the relation between the two definitions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is the *espace etale* of a presheaf, which is Exercise 1.13 of Hartshorne.

For a presheaf $F$ on $X$, its espace etale is a topological space which as a set is just the disjoint union $Spe(F) := \bigsqcup_{x\in X} F_x$ of the stalks, equipped with a map
$$f : Spe(F)\rightarrow X$$
which sends everything in $F_x$ to $x$. For any section $s\in F(U)$ for some open $U\subset X$, we then get a map $\overline{s} : U\rightarrow Spe(F)$ given by sending $x\mapsto s_x$, where $s_x$ is the image of $s$ in the stalk $F_x$. This is a set-theoretic section to $f$, which becomes a continuous section upon declaring the topology on $Spe(F)$ to be the strongest topology such that all such maps $\overline{s} : U\rightarrow Spe(F)$ are continuous (for all open $U\subset X$).

Then, the sheafification of $F$ is precisely the sheaf whose sections over $U\subset X$ are the **continuous sections** of the map $f : Spe(F)\rightarrow X$ over $U$.

Comment: Does $Spe(F)$ have a scheme structure (say when $F$ is coherent or quasicoherent)? e.g. is it $\mathbf{Spec}$ of some sheaf of algebras? If $F$ is locally free, then we can use $Sym^\bullet(F^\ast)$, but in general?